# formatting money with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote this little snippet that should format money but its failing on the period for some reason. It keeps adding them every time ...any idea why and is there a better way of doing this

```
$(".dollar").blur(function() {
    var curval = $(this).val(); 
    if ($(this).val().indexOf("$") != 0) {
        $(this).val("$" + $(this).val());
    } 
    if ($(this).val().indexOf(".") != 0){
        $(this).val($(this).val() + ".00");
    }
});
```

Comment: `indexOf` returns `-1` if the string is not found.

Comment: You are checking if the index of the . is not 0, that is, on the LHS of the value.  this would only match something like `.50`, I suspect you instead simply want to check if a . exists, in which case just check ` indexOf('.') != -1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote a different dollar formatting snippet that will take any number (1, 1.6, 2.52, 8.2472) and automatically format it to dollar notation ($1.00, $1.60, $2.52, $8.24):

```
$('.dollars').blur(function(e){
    var curVal = parseFloat($(this).val()),
        curInt = parseInt(curVal, 10),
        curDec = parseInt(curVal*100, 10) - parseInt(curInt*100, 10);

    curDec = (curDec < 10) ? "0" + curDec : curDec;

    if (!isNaN(curInt) && !isNaN(curDec)) {
        $(this).val("$"+curInt+"."+curDec);
    }
});
```

[See it in action here.](http://jsfiddle.net/drAxb/)

Answer (score 3):

You may take a look at the [jquery globalization plugin](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/10/jquery-globalization-plugin-from-microsoft.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

The "indexOf" function returns the index into the string. I think you should be testing to see if the result is less than zero.

```
if ($(this).val().indexOf("$") < 0) {
    $(this).val("$" + $(this).val());
} 
if ($(this).val().indexOf(".") < 0){
    $(this).val($(this).val() + ".00");
```

*edit* oops — I had it backwards :-) Less than zero, not greater than or equal to.  The latter is what you'd do to find out if the character **is** in the string, but your code needs to know when it's **not** in the string.

Comment: @Tamer: You got away with it when searching for $ because the $ would probably be the first character in the array, in position 0. The decimal point could be at many positions, 0 or greater.